# UpdateTargetTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Does such thing exist (like UpdateSourceTrigger exists) or is it possible somehow? I'd like to only update the target when I want to. One-time binding won't work, because I don't want it to update one time - I'd like to update it when I want to, not when the bound object changes.

So my question is very simple: how to NOT change the target when the source changes, but change the target when something is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing you can do is use an attached behavior that hooks into some event that isn't directly related to your binding. Below is a skeleton of some working code just to give you some ideas.

```
internal class ContactcControlPropertySetter : Behavior<ContentControl>
{
    protected override void OnAttached() {
        base.OnAttached();
        if (AssociatedObject == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("AssociatedObject must not be null");

        AssociatedObject.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
        CultureManager.UICultureChanged += OnCultureChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching() {
        AssociatedObject.DataContextChanged -= OnDataContextChanged;
        CultureManager.UICultureChanged -= OnCultureChanged;
    }

    private void OnCultureChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SetProperties();
    }

    private void SetProperties()
    {
        ...
        var tooltipFmt = _resourceManager.GetString(key, culture);
        ...
        AssociatedObject.ToolTip = tooltip;
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just rebind data in code behind when it is needed. 
Or try
BindingExpression.UpdateTarget ()

Answer (score 0):

If you know the condition beforehand where you don't want UI to update, how about not raising the `PropertyChangedEvent` in that case. (in case you are implementing `INPC` on your `ViewModel` class).

I know this won't work with `Dependency Property` since `PropertyChangedEvent` is handled internally by DP's. But in case of normal `CLR properties` it will work. eg -

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

**ViewModel -**

```
public string Name
{
   get { return name; }
   set
   {
      name = value;
      if(UpdateUI) // Your condition here
      {
         OnPropertyChanged("Name");
      }
   }
}
```